# Find the integral values of K for which the system of equations possess solutions and find those solutions;

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos^{-1}x+(\sin^{-1}y)^2=\dfrac{K\pi^2}{4}$$
$$(\sin^{-1}y)^2\cdot\cos^{-1}x=\dfrac{\pi^4}{16}$$

Assuming these as roots of quadratic equation

Lets $\cos^{-1}x=\alpha, (\sin^{-1}y)^2=\beta$

$$x^2-Sx+P=0$$
$$x^2-\dfrac{K\pi^2}{4}x+\dfrac{\pi^4}{16}=0$$
$$16x^2-4K\pi^2x+\pi^4=0$$

As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real, so $D>=0$ to have real solutions

$$16K^2\pi^4-64\pi^4>=0$$
$$K^2-4>=0$$
$$K\in(-\infty,-2] \cup [2,\infty)$$

Now $\alpha$ should be in the range $[0,\pi]$ and $\beta$ should be in the range $\left[0,\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}\right]$.

Their intersection will be $\left[0,\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}\right]$

$$x=\dfrac{4K\pi^2\pm\sqrt{16K^2\pi^4-64\pi^4}}{32}$$
$$x=\dfrac{K\pi^2\pm\pi^2\sqrt{K^2-4}}{8}$$

So there are two solutions, let's take first solution

$$x=\dfrac{K\pi^2+\pi^2\sqrt{K^2-4}}{8}$$
$$0\le\dfrac{K\pi^2+\pi^2\sqrt{K^2-4}}{8}\le\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$$
$$K+\sqrt{K^2-4}\ge0 \text { and } {K+\sqrt{K^2-4}}\le2 $$

So here $K=2$ is the only solution for above inequality.

Let's take second solution

$$x=\dfrac{K\pi^2-\pi^2\sqrt{K^2-4}}{8}$$
$$0\le\dfrac{K\pi^2-\pi^2\sqrt{K^2-4}}{8}\le\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$$
$$K-\sqrt{K^2-4}\ge0 \text { and } {K-\sqrt{K^2-4}}\le2 $$

$$K\ge2 \text { and } {K-2}\le\sqrt{K^2-4} $$

$(K-2)$ will be greater than equal to zero

$$K\ge2 \text { and } {K^2+4-4K}\le{K^2-4} $$ 
$$K\ge2 \text { and } K\ge2 $$

Now this says $\forall K\ge2$, solution will exist.

But answer is only $K=2$. What's the point I am missing.

Comment: $\alpha$ is $\cos^{-1}x$, not $\cos x$, so range of $cos^{-1}x$ will be $[0,\pi]$

Comment: It is incorrect that $x_-\in[0,\pi^2/4]$ or $x_+\in[0,\pi^2/4]$. The correct condition is that $x_-\in[0,\pi^2/4]$ *and* $x_+\in[0,\color{red}{\pi}]$.